# More simultaneous RDS into a Windows VM on GCP without AD

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have spun up a Windows VM compute engine to host a software application(exe) from a 3rd party vendor.

Multiple users (>15) will need to use this application simultaneously so they will need to RDS into the VM through their user accounts.
We have set up Cloud IAP. Currently 2 users can access the VM simulatenously as is expected because the VM provides 2 RDS licenses.

We are trying to get more licenses but apparently an Azure AD is required for those licenses to work. Is there away to have more licenses without the Azure AD or without hosting a new AD on google?

I just want to be able to have >15 people simultaneously accessing the application on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure Windows RDS without a domain, keep in mind that you need to purchase Device CAL's - **User CALs can only be used in an AD environment**; and you are limiting your options for high availability.Check the following links for guidance:

[Deploying a RDSH Server in a Workgroup – RDS 2012 R2](https://ryanmangansitblog.com/2013/10/30/deploying-a-rdsh-server-in-a-workgroup-rds-2012-r2/)

[Windows Server 2019 Remote Desktop Services without Domain](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2020/06/windows-server-2019-remote-desktop-services-without-domain/)

[RDS Without Domain](https://youtu.be/AM9azw1D7hM)

Comment: The second link is very good - nice find.